# SQL: Is there a way to iteratively DECLARE a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, variables, reportbuilder3.0

Is there a way to accomplish something like this in SQL:

```
DECLARE @iter = 1

WHILE @iter<11
BEGIN
DECLARE @('newdate'+@iter) DATE = [some expression that generates a value]
SET @iter = @iter + 1
END
```

At the end I would have 10 variables:

```
@newdate1
@newdate2
@newdate3
@newdate4
@newdate5
@newdate6
@newdate7
@newdate8
@newdate9
@newdate10
```

**Update:**

Based on a comment, I think I should specify *why* I want to do this. I am working with Report Builder 3.0. I am going to make a report where the input will be a `start date` and an `end date` (in addition to one other parameter). This will generate data between the date range. However, the user also wants to check the same date range for all other years in the set 2013 -> current year.

The tricky part is this: the user can enter a date range in **any** year between 2013 and the current year and I need to return data for the input year and also data for the other years. For example, if the user enters in 1/1/2014 - 6/1/2014 then I need to return the same range but for the years 2013, 2015, and 2016.

Example input:

```
1/1/2016 - 6/1/2016
```

Report must generate data for these values:

```
1/1/2013 - 6/1/2013
1/1/2014 - 6/1/2014
1/1/2015 - 6/1/2015
1/1/2016 - 6/1/2016
```

If there is a better way to do this, I'm all ears.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using (presumably SQL Server).  And (2) No.  There is no way to do this simply.

Comment: Why would you want to? There's likely a better way to do whatever it is you are trying to do. Temp tables or temp table var, for example.

Comment: @Nikki9696 there probably is. I'll edit my question with the over-arching goal.

Comment: Most likely you're looking for a temporary table.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is having a table variable hold key/value pairs and you reference that every time you need a value (e.g. `SELECT value FROM @table WHERE key = 'newdate1'`, or simply `JOIN` to this table).

Comment: Agree with Cory, I'd use a select to generate the dates and JOIN to it

Comment: @TabAlleman I began to do that but I couldn't finish it. I inserted key value pairs for the years 2013, 2014, and 2015, but this is not dynamic at all. What if the user picks the date range 1/1/2014 - 6/1/2014? I need the table to be filled dynamically I guess...

Comment: You could just use variable for the StartDate & EndDate, and use DATEADD logic to get the other years.   There are numerous other ways you could do this in the WHERE clause without 10 variables.

Comment: I apologize everyone but I did not realize that I forgot to mention in the question that the date range can be within **any** of the years and I need to return all *other* years. I kind of mentioned it in one comment though. But anyways, that's the goal.

Comment: In SQL Server, variable declarations don't participate in control flow **at all**. A Variable is valid from the point of its `DECLARE` statement until the end of the batch, even if that `DECLARE` is inside an `IF` block that evaluates to false. You *definitely* can't declare variables in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a UDF to create Dynamic Date Ranges.

For exanple

```
Select DateR1=RetVal,DateR2=DateAdd(MM,5,RetVal) from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2013-01-01','2016-01-01','YY',1)
```

Returns

```
DateR1      DateR2
2013-01-01  2013-06-01
2014-01-01  2014-06-01
2015-01-01  2015-06-01
2016-01-01  2016-06-01
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date] (@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@DatePart varchar(10),@Incr int)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal datetime)

As
Begin
    With DateTable As (
        Select DateFrom = @DateFrom
        Union All
        Select Case @DatePart
               When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               End
        From DateTable DF
        Where DF.DateFrom < @DateTo
    )

    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal) Select DateFrom From DateTable option (maxrecursion 32767)

    Return
End

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','DD',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-31','MI',15) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-02','SS',1)
```

Stripped Down version - NON UDF
This can be injected into your SQL

```
Declare @startdate Date ='1/1/2014'   -- user supplied value
Declare @enddate Date = '6/1/2014'    -- user supplied value

Declare @DateFrom Date = cast('2013-'+cast(month(@StartDate) as varchar(10))+'-'+cast(Day(@StartDate) as varchar(10)) as date)
Declare @DateTo Date   = cast(cast(Year(GetDate()) as varchar(10))+'-'+cast(month(@enddate) as varchar(10))+'-'+cast(Day(@enddate) as varchar(10)) as date) 
Declare @Incr int = DateDiff(MM,@startdate,@enddate)  -- made to be dynamic based on the user supplied dates

Declare @DateRange Table (DateR1 date,DateR2 Date)

;with DateTable As (
    Select DateFrom = @DateFrom
    Union All
    Select DateAdd(YY, 1, df.dateFrom)
    From DateTable DF
    Where DF.DateFrom < @DateTo
)
Insert into @DateRange(DateR1,DateR2) Select DateR1=DateFrom,DateR2=DateAdd(MM,@Incr,DateFrom) From DateTable option (maxrecursion 32767)

Select * from @DateRange
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you're looking to generate lists of things that differ numerically (incrementally, etc.), think of using a [Tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) (a table of numbers). Generating dates is a great application for a tally table:

```
declare @startDate date = '20160101'
declare @endDate date = '20160601'

select N
    , dateadd(year, (N - 1) * -1, @startDate) as StartDate
    , dateadd(year, (N - 1) * -1, @endDate) as EndDate
from tally -- Follow the link above for info on how to create this table
where N <= 4
order by N desc
```

Result:

```
N   StartDate   EndDate
4   2013-01-01  2013-06-01
3   2014-01-01  2014-06-01
2   2015-01-01  2015-06-01
1   2016-01-01  2016-06-01
```

Making calculations with a tally table in a query will often be much more efficient than loops, cursors, or dynamic SQL. In this case, compared to other answers presented, I'd say it's easier to program and maintain as well.

After seeing several of the other answers, I must say that I strongly encourage you to **NOT** create tons of numbered variables to hold these values. This would often be poor style in other languages where you might use an array or list or some other data structure, let alone SQL where **sets and the means to manipulate and store them are fundamental to the language itself**.

Perhaps I'm not seeing your particular use case, but even if you create these numbered variables using code, you'll then have to write *more* code to actually call these variables in any subsequent logic or calculations.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Invalid object name 'tally'`.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat - did you follow the *link* to Tally Table's that Tim has provided and actually *create one* before attempting to use the code in his answer?

Answer (score 2):

First, create a numbers table like this.

```
declare @numbers table(n int)
insert into @Numbers(N)
select top 1000 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
from   master..spt_values t1 
       cross join master..spt_values t2
```

then create dates like this

```
    declare @iniDate date
    declare @endDate date
    delcare @limitDate date

    set @iniDate='20160101'
    set @enddate='20160106'
    set @limitDate ='20130101'

    select dateadd(yy,-1*(n-1),@inidate), dateadd(yy,-1*(n-1),@enddate) 
    from @numbers where (n-1)<=datediff(yy, @limitDate, @inidate)
```

EDIT:
After new request, try this:

```
declare @iniDate date
declare @endDate date
declare @iniLimitDate date
declare @endLimitDate date

set @iniDate='20140201'
set @endDate='20140206'
set @iniLimitDate ='20130101'
set @endLimitDate ='20161231'    

select datefromparts(year(@iniLimitDate)+n-1,month(@iniDate), day(@iniDate))
    ,datefromparts(year(@iniLimitDate)+n-1,month(@endDate), day(@endDate))
from @numbers 
where  year(@iniLimitDate)+n-1<=year(@endlimitdate)
    and year(@iniLimitDate)+n-1<>year(@enddate)
```

NOTE: *It needs to be fixed for feb 29*

Comment: This answer only works for 2016. I need to allow the user to input any year and get the date ranges in all other years.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat user will set `@iniDate` and `@endDate` as they need

Comment: Yes. For example, I tried your code with `@iniDate = 20140101` and `@enddate = 20140106` and it returns `1/1/2014 - 1/6/2014` and `1/1/2013 - 1/6/2013`

Comment: It's missing the 2015 and 2016.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat your request was from input date back to 2013. What exactly do you need?

Comment: Ah yes, I was not thinking clearly. I meant something different than what I wrote. Consider this: 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016. If the user inputs, for example, 2014, how do I return 2013, 2015, 2016?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat see my edit. `datefromparts()` function works on SQL 2012 and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?  It uses dynamic SQL to build a query.  I don't know about your date formats, but I used cast to sever the time portion from the standard getDate() function just in case.

```
DECLARE @iter int = 1
Declare @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE @iter<11
BEGIN
SET @SQL = ISNULL(@SQL,'') + ' DECLARE @newdate'+ CAST(@iter AS VARCHAR) + ' DATE = ' + CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS VARCHAR) + ' ' 
PRINT (@SQL)
SET @iter = @iter + 1
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' SELECT * FROM blah'
EXEC @SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

John has a fancier solution than my simple example here, but this one doesn't need a separate UDF. In case you don't have permissions for those or something.

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME, @tmpStartDate DATETIME, @tmpEndDate DATETIME 
SET @startDate = '1/1/2016'
SET @endDate = '6/1/2016'


SET @tmpStartDate = @startDate
SET @tmpEndDate = @endDate
DECLARE @dateTbl TABLE (startDate DATETIME, endDate DATETIME)

WHILE (DATEPART(YEAR, @tmpStartDate) >= 2013)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @dateTbl VALUES (@tmpStartDate, @tmpEndDate)
    SET @tmpStartDate = DATEADD(year, -1, @tmpStartDate)
    SET @tmpEndDate = DATEADD(year, -1, @tmpStartDate)
END

SELECT * FROM @dateTbl
```

Comment: Not fancier,  I'm just REALLY lazy, and I often require date ranges

Comment: Well, your solution is elegant, I like it  =)

Comment: This answer only works if they input dates in 2016. My question is a bit tricky because the user could enter a date range within any year and I then must return all *other* years.

Answer (score 1):

Other methods mentioned are much better for what you are trying to do, but in terms of answering the question "Is there a way to iteratively DECLARE a variable?", you could do something like what I have below using dynamic SQL.  Basically you would create a string, using a loop, that contains your declare statements.  Then you would create an additional string (or strings) to use them.  In this example, I'm simply creating the variables and setting them to today's date.  Then I select each variable.

```
DECLARE @iter INT = 1, @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '', @MoreSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

WHILE @iter < 11
BEGIN
    SET @SQL += 'DECLARE @NewDate' + CAST(@iter AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' DATE = GETDATE() '

    SET @iter += 1
END

SET @iter = 1

WHILE @iter < 11
BEGIN
    SET @MoreSQL  += 'SELECT @NewDate' + CAST(@iter AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' '

    SET @iter += 1
END

SET @SQL += @MoreSQL

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: One should mention that variables that are created in the context of a dynamic SQL statement can only be used in that same dynamic SQL context.

Answer (score 0):

To get start/end ranges only for last 4 years:

```
DECLARE @START DATETIME, @END DATETIME

SET @START='2016-01-01'
SET @END='2016-06-01'

DECLARE @DATES TABLE (STARTDATE DATETIME, ENDDATE DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @DATES (STARTDATE, ENDDATE)
SELECT @START,@END UNION
SELECT DATEADD(YY,-1,@START),DATEADD(YY,-1,@END) UNION
SELECT DATEADD(YY,-2,@START),DATEADD(YY,-2,@END) UNION
SELECT DATEADD(YY,-3,@START),DATEADD(YY,-3,@END)

SELECT * FROM @DATES ORDER BY STARTDATE
```

To get all dates in between:

```
DECLARE @START DATETIME, @END DATETIME

SET @START='2016-01-01'
SET @END='2016-06-01'

DECLARE @CURDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @DATES TABLE (DATEVAL DATETIME)

SET @CURDATE=@START

WHILE @CURDATE<=@END
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @DATES (DATEVAL)
    SELECT @CURDATE UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(YY,-1,@CURDATE) UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(YY,-2,@CURDATE) UNION
    SELECT DATEADD(YY,-3,@CURDATE) 

    SET @CURDATE=DATEADD(DD,1,@CURDATE)
END

SELECT * FROM @DATES ORDER BY DATEVAL
```

To get all years from @START to 2013...

```
DECLARE @START DATETIME, @END DATETIME

SET @START='2016-01-01'
SET @END='2016-06-01'

DECLARE @DATES TABLE (STARTDATE DATETIME, ENDDATE DATETIME)

DECLARE @CURYEAR INT
SET @CURYEAR=YEAR(@START)

WHILE @CURYEAR>= 2013 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @DATES (STARTDATE, ENDDATE)
    SELECT @START,@END 

    SET @START = DATEADD(YY,-1,@START)
    SET @END = DATEADD(YY,-1,@END)
    SET @CURYEAR=YEAR(@START)
END
SELECT * FROM @DATES ORDER BY STARTDATE
```

Comment: This seems to be very close to what I need, but I need to allow the user to input a date range in **any** year and return data for that year + all other years.

Comment: Easily tweaked for that, but there must be a finite range to "all other years" or a method of determining said range.

Comment: I have added a 3rd statement which might be what you want.

Comment: Yikes I never submitted the comment. Yea the finite range is 2013 -> current year.