# Populate the number ranges & concatenate with text in the child table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

Wondering how to build a logic for the below scenario (I am using SQL Server 2008 & above).

In TblMaster each record will have a Start value and an End value. Along with that a CharToAdd varchar column as well. If the range says 1 to 3 then in the TblDetails there should be an entry for 1,2,3. Not sure whether I am explaining it effectively so have provided a screenshot with sample input/output as well.

Ranges would be anywhere between 5000 to 100000 (max) so performance is a concern as well.

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VMaster](
    [VID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [VName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblMaster](
    [SID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    [VID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] default (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [CharToAdd] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Start] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [End] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblDetails](
    [DetailsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    [SID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Sno] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ConcatenatedText] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [isIssued] [bit] default (0) NOT NULL,
    [isUsed] [bit] default (0) NOT NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblMaster]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [fk_SI_id] FOREIGN KEY([VID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[VMaster] ([VID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblMaster] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_SI_id]
GO
```

**Sample data for the tables:**

```
Insert into dbo.VMaster Values ('A1')
GO
Insert into dbo.TblMaster Values (1,default, 'ABC', 100, 105)
GO
```

**Sample records inserted into the tables and the output expected in TblDetails:**
[image]

**EDIT:** What if the record in TblMaster is getting updated later? If both the bit fields in TblDetails are 0 for all the corresponding auto-generated rows then should delete the old records and regenerate based on the "new range" updated.

```
--Modifying the original range. So the records 100, 104, 105 has to be removed 
-- from tblDetails if its isIssued, isUsed are both 0. 
-- If not will have to reject this update 
Update dbo.TblMaster 
Set Start = 101, [End] = 103
Where SID = 1

--Another scenario. We need to remove 100,101,102,103,104,105 from tblDetails if
-- its isIssued, isUsed are both 0. Then create entries from 1000 to 1500 in tblDetails. 
-- If isIssued, isUsed are not 0 then will have to reject this update 
Update dbo.TblMaster 
Set Start = 1000, [End] = 1500
Where SID = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a UDF to create Dynamic Ranges.  A Numbers or Tally Table would do the same

```
Declare @Table table (SID int,VID int,CreateDate DateTime,CharToAdd varchar(25),Start int, [End] Int)
Insert Into @Table values
(1,1,'2016-06-30 19:56:14.560','ABC',100,105),
(2,2,'2016-06-30 19:56:14.560','ABC',10,15)

Declare @Min int,@Max int
Select @Min=min(Start),@Max=max([End]) From @Table

Select B.SID
      ,Sno = A.RetVal
      ,ConcetratedText = concat(B.CharToAdd,A.RetVal)
 From (Select RetVal=Cast(RetVal as int) from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](@Min,@Max,1)) A
 Join @Table B on A.RetVal Between B.Start and B.[End]
 Order By B.Sid,A.RetVal
```

Returns

```
SID Sno ConcetratedText
1   100 ABC100
1   101 ABC101
1   102 ABC102
1   103 ABC103
1   104 ABC104
1   105 ABC105
2   10  ABC10
2   11  ABC11
2   12  ABC12
2   13  ABC13
2   14  ABC14
2   15  ABC15
```

The UDF if you care to use it  (you may have to set maxrecursion to 0)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number] (@R1 money,@R2 money,@Incr money)

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](0,100,2)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal money)

As
Begin
    With NumbTable as (
        Select NumbFrom = @R1
        union all
        Select nf.NumbFrom + @Incr
        From NumbTable nf
        Where nf.NumbFrom < @R2
    )
    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal)

    Select NumbFrom from NumbTable Option (maxrecursion 32767)

    Return
End
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited the question can you please check that and if possible update your answer?

Comment: Not understanding the change.  Can you post a sample?

Comment: Have updated the edit with couple of samples. Please check whether that helps

Comment: No change needed.  The query is dynamic.  The Numeric range is based of the min(Start) and max([End])  ... HATE THAT FIELD NAME.

Comment: I did try running a update statement with start as 101 and end as 103. But the old records (100, 104,105) still stays in tblDetails. Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: In your answer before the SELECT stmt I have added Insert into tblDetails (SID, Sno,ConcatenatedText) for persisting the results into the table. So now if I try updating tblMaster the old records would still be here right?

Comment: Did you change ALL  "@Table" to your table name after the Declare @Min?  You can also remove the first 4 lines of code which create a temporary table

Comment: Just to be clear.  You need from Declare Min on...  and replace @Table with YOUR table name

Comment: OK I think I'm catching up with you.   In your updated answer you had an UPDATE while in the messages you did a INSERT.  Do you have two records for ID 1?

Comment: No one record only. I am saying initially inserted with some range say 100 to 105. Now trying to update the "same" record with a different range say 101 to 103.

Comment: Added another answer to illustrate the change

Comment: Saw your another answer - I don't think you got the edit part of the question still :).  That is not what I was asking. Anyways forget it your answer was working for the "original" question so will go ahead and mark it as an answer!! Thanks!

Comment: Why did you use type `money`?

Comment: @shawnt00 completely arbitrary.   in the UDF the increment could be a decimal. I've never really cared beyond 4 decimals

Comment: In this case I think and integer is clearly better. But you should note that `money` has rounding problems in case you weren't aware of that.

Comment: @shawnt00  The UDF is designed to be generic and portable.  I have 1 function which serves many applications.   In short, it's a dynamic numbers or tally table.

Comment: I hadn't looked close enough to notice you allow fractional increments. I think I would still argue that `decimal` would be better. But it's cool :)

Comment: @shawnt00 similar technique for dates  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843303/sql-is-there-a-way-to-iteratively-declare-a-variable/37843630#37843630

Answer (score 1):

Go recursive :

```
    ;with recur as (select vid, chartoadd, [start] as nm, [end], 1 as Detailsid  from tblMaster
                   union all
                   select vid, chartoadd, nm+1, [end], Detailsid+1  from recur where nm<[end])
    select Detailsid, vid, chartoadd+cast(nm as char) as ConcatenatedText
      from recur
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**OUPUT**

```
Detailsid   vid ConcatenatedText
1   1   ABC100                           
2   1   ABC101                           
3   1   ABC102                           
4   1   ABC103                           
5   1   ABC104                           
6   1   ABC105
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This script will each time consider all records in tblMaster to populate tbldetails table which might be costly. Also how to make sure of this result to Insert into the details table?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use one of many tricks for creating a list of numbers. What's probably easiest for you is to actually create one in the database. I'll leave that task up to you. So let's assume you have a `Numbers` table with values from 0 up to the maximum possible rows in a range.

```
select ...
from
    Master m
    inner join Numbers n
        on n.Number between 0 and m.End - m.Start
    inner join Details d
        d.Sno = n.Number + m.Start /* and d.SID = m.SID ? */
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example illustrates how it is dynamic

Notice the UPDATE

```
Declare @Table table (SID int,VID int,CreateDate DateTime,CharToAdd varchar(25),Start int, [End] Int)
Insert Into @Table values
(1,1,'2016-06-30 19:56:14.560','ABC',1000,1500),
(2,2,'2016-06-30 19:56:14.560','ABC',10,15)

-----------------------------------------------------------
Update @Table Set Start=101,[End]=103 where SID=1
----------------------------------------------------------

Declare @Min int,@Max int
Select @Min=min(Start),@Max=max([End]) From @Table


Select B.SID
      ,Sno = A.RetVal
      ,ConcetratedText = concat(B.CharToAdd,A.RetVal)
 From (Select RetVal=Cast(RetVal as int) from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](@Min,@Max,1)) A
 Join @Table B on A.RetVal Between B.Start and B.[End]
 Order By B.Sid,A.RetVal
```

Returns

```
SID Sno ConcetratedText
1   101 ABC101            --<< 101 - 103 not 1000 - 1500
1   102 ABC102            --<< 101 - 103 not 1000 - 1500
1   103 ABC103            --<< 101 - 103 not 1000 - 1500
2   10  ABC10
2   11  ABC11
2   12  ABC12
2   13  ABC13
2   14  ABC14
2   15  ABC15
```