# Converting a working script into Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

Posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126830/populate-the-number-ranges-concatenate-with-text-in-the-child-table) yesterday and got a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38127334/1480322) as well. The solution script works fine as-is but when I converted it into a stored procedure it gives wrong results. Not able to identify where exactly I am messing up with the code.

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VMaster](
    [VID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [VName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblMaster](
    [SID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    [VID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] default (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [CharToAdd] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Start] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [End] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblDetails](
    [DetailsID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    [SID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Sno] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ConcatenatedText] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [isIssued] [bit] default (0) NOT NULL,
    [isUsed] [bit] default (0) NOT NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblMaster]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [fk_SI_id] FOREIGN KEY([VID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[VMaster] ([VID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TblMaster] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_SI_id]
GO
```

**Working solution:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number] (@R1 money,@R2 money,@Incr money)

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](0,100,2)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal money)

As
Begin
    With NumbTable as (
        Select NumbFrom = @R1
        union all
        Select nf.NumbFrom + @Incr
        From NumbTable nf
        Where nf.NumbFrom < @R2
    )
    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal)

    Select NumbFrom from NumbTable Option (maxrecursion 32767)

    Return
End


Declare @Table table (SID int,VID int,CreateDate DateTime,CharToAdd varchar(25),Start int, [End] Int)
Insert Into @Table values
(1,1,'2016-06-30 19:56:14.560','ABC',1,5),
(2,1,'2016-06-30 19:56:14.560','XYZ',10,20),
(3,2,'2016-06-30 19:56:14.560','P1',10,15)

Declare @Min int,@Max int
Select @Min=min(Start),@Max=max([End]) From @Table

Select B.SID
      ,Sno = A.RetVal
      ,ConcetratedText = concat(B.CharToAdd,A.RetVal)
 From (Select RetVal=Cast(RetVal as int) from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](@Min,@Max,1)) A
 Join @Table B on A.RetVal Between B.Start and B.[End]
 Order By B.Sid,A.RetVal
```

**Stored procedure (This generates more records than the working solution!!)**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add_Details]
(
    @VID          INT,
    @CreatedDate     DATETIME,
    @CharToAdd      VARCHAR(10),
    @Start       INT,
    @End         INT
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
    DECLARE @SID INT

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TblMaster] (VID, CreatedDate, CharToAdd, Start, [End]) 
    VALUES (@VID, @CreatedDate, @CharToAdd, @Start, @End)
    SET @SID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    DECLARE @Min INT, @Max INT
    SELECT @Min = @Start, @Max = @End

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TblDetails] (SID, Sno, [ConcatenatedText])
    SELECT @SID
          ,Sno = A.RetVal
          ,ConcatenatedText = CONCAT(B.CharToAdd,A.RetVal)
     FROM (SELECT RetVal = CAST(RetVal AS INT) FROM [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](@Min,@Max,1)) A 
            JOIN dbo.TblMaster B ON A.RetVal BETWEEN B.Start AND B.[End]
     ORDER BY B.SID,A.RetVal

END
GO


Declare @tmp datetime
Set @tmp = getdate()

EXEC    [dbo].[Add_Details]
        @VID = 1,
        @CreatedDate = @tmp,
        @CharToAdd = 'ABC',
        @Start = 1,
        @End = 5

EXEC    [dbo].[Add_Details]
        @VID = 1,
        @CreatedDate = @tmp,
        @CharToAdd = 'XYZ',
        @Start = 10,
        @End = 20

EXEC    [dbo].[Add_Details]
        @VID = 2,
        @CreatedDate = @tmp,
        @CharToAdd = 'P1',
        @Start = 10,
        @End = 15
```

**Output of working script:**

[image]

**Output of the stored procedure:**

[image]

Comment: You really should help us out by telling us what's actually different in the output.

Comment: @shawnt00 Have added the results of both working script as well as the stored procedure.

Comment: Maybe you should just delete everything and try again to make sure those  rows weren't already in the table from earlier testing.

Comment: I had truncated the table and ran it fresh and each time those additional rows gets added.

Comment: Yes, I guess the `DetailsID` would have been out of sequence then.

Comment: Since I have truncated both masters and details table multiple times and tried it out without success somehow feel that my Stored procedure itself is buggy in someway. But I am not able to identify it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter by `VID` on the second insert. It's picking up rows from previous executions. Since it only picks up other rows where the ranges are overlapping it doesn't always do it. Run the procedure a few more times and you'll see the duplication amplified a lot more. The reason it didn't do this in the original code was because you were using a temp table that was recreated each time you ran it.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TblDetails] (SID, Sno, [ConcatenatedText])
SELECT @SID
      ,Sno = A.RetVal
      ,ConcatenatedText = CONCAT(B.CharToAdd,A.RetVal)
FROM (
    SELECT RetVal = CAST(RetVal AS INT)
    FROM [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Number](@Min,@Max,1)) A 
        JOIN dbo.TblMaster B ON A.RetVal BETWEEN B.Start AND B.[End]
    WHERE B.VID = @VID -- <<<---------
)
```

On a side note I would highly recommend changing that function to type `int` rather than `money`.

Comment: Thanks shwawnt00 it really helped. Yeah I have changed the data type too.

Comment: Looks like it hasn't fixed the problem. The same issue is happening again!

Comment: @prasanth Are you re-using (duplicating) VIDs?

Comment: Yes in tblMaster VID can be duplicated. Combination of VID and CharToAdd will be unique though.

Comment: @prasanth Then you'll need to add that filter to the `where` clause along with the other one we put in.

Comment: Cool thanks. In the tblMaster the Ranges (Column Start & End) would be anywhere between 5000 to 100000 (max) and performance is a concern. Do you foresee any issues with this script or anything specific need to be done so that this performs better?

Comment: That recursive function might be a problem. Obviously you'll want to look at indexing.

Comment: Then I should google about your suggestion in my original post about using Numbers table instead